# Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'quicksand'

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, quicksand

I purchased a bootstrap template and I have been trying to integrate it work on my Rails app.

I have some buttons in an unorder list:

```
<ul class="filter-nav">
  <li class="active"><a data-id="all" href="">All</a></li>
  <% @categories.each do |category| %>
    <li><a data-id="<%= category.name %>" href=""><%= category.name %></a></li>
  <% end %> 
</ul>
```

Which when are clicked are sorting images:

```
<ul class="thumbnails" id="thumbnails">

<table>
  <% @designs.each_with_index do |d, i| %>
  <% strcategory =  Category.find(d.category) %>
  <% if i % 4 == 0 %>
  <tr>
    <% end %>
    <td>
      <li class="span3" data-id="<%=i+1%>" data-type="<%= strcategory.name %>">
        <a href="<%=d.image_url.to_s%>" class="thumbnail">
          <img src="<%=d.image_url(:thumb).to_s%>" alt="<%= d.name %>" />
          <span class="caption"><i class="icon-plus-sign"></i></span>
        </a>
        <% if current_user %>
        <%= link_to 'edit', edit_design_path(d) %> | <%= link_to 'delete',  d,  method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
        <% end %>
      </li>
    </td>
    <% if i % 4 == 3 %>
    </tr>
    <% end %>
    <% end %>
  </table>

</ul>
```

When I click a button I get this error: Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'quicksand' on photographer.js file (on the first line):

```
        $thumbnails.quicksand($filteredData, {
      duration: 800,
      easing: 'easeInOutQuad'
    }, function() {
        Shadowbox.setup("a.thumbnail");
    });

    $('.filter-nav li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).parent().addClass('active');

    return false;

});
```

I include jquery.quicksand.js (version 1.2.2) in the assets/javascripts folder. Somebody else had a [similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10338513/jquery-uncaught-typeerror-object-object-has-no-method-quicksand) and the solution was to remove the 2nd copy of jQuery. I am not sure if I include a second jQuery file, at least there is not any in my assets. Just the jquery.quicksand.js and jquery.easing.js. Well, I tried removing those two files but this didn't solve the problem (if that is what I was suppose to do).

Here is also my gemfile just for the record:

```
gem 'rails', '4.0.2'
gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 2.3.2.2'
gem 'devise'
gem 'figaro'
gem 'simple_form'
gem 'carrierwave'
gem 'rmagick'
gem 'thin'
```

Let me know if you have any clue of whats wrong or if you need any other information. Thank you for your effort looking this up for me.

Comment: This is pretty weird `<% strcategory =  Category.find(d.category) %>`.  Rails Associations should probably be handling that for you.

Comment: I see thanks but thats not what bothers me.